# SwiftUI ForEach DisclosureGroup .onDelete = Index out of range

Tags: list, swiftui, foreach

Remove subitems work good, but remove item give me present:

"Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:575: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Plz help! =)

[App view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68YAU.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ypre.png)

[Create data code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LCfc.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please don not post images of code. Post the actual code so others can copy and run it on their own to be able to help you debug it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.